# mysqli not working, module not found

Tags: php, apache

I am new to PHP and web servers, and i was going to make a website using PHP. I found a free login script that uses mysqli. Every time I go on the page it says I don't have mysqli? I am running Apache with PHP3. The mysqli part of the script is thus:

```
// if the connection is successfully established
if($conn = new mysqli($this->conn_datas['localhost'], $this->conn_datas['daztestc_testdaz'], $this->conn_datas['dj2403ms81'], $this->conn_datas['daztestc_daztest'])) {
  $sql = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
  $conn->query($sql);
  $this->conn = $conn;          // add the connection in the $conn property
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. But, phew, can we have a _bit_ of formatting to your question please? Use the edit button, and add some paragraphing and code formatting (use the code button for the latter).

Comment: @hd1 - well, that's very kind of you to ask. I had a very pleasant meal with a friend today (plus late Christmas presents) and the snow looks very beautiful outside my window. So yes, I think I am. Trust you are also!

Comment: Can you recheck your version of PHP? Version 3 has been dead some many years `:)`

Answer (score 4):

php3? mysqli was not introduced until php5. where did you find a server with such an old copy of php? and is any of the code working? as most things have changed since php3.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have MySQLI extension installed. Check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) to know how to enable it. Ah... of course... you can't use it on PHP3... so if you really want, upgrade your server.